# Unable to get <li> ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I'm using this code to get ID of li, but I am able to get only ul ID. Below is the code. Can anyone help me.

```
$("#trash ul li").click(function(event) {
    var $item = $(this),
    $target = $(event.target);
    //recycleImage($item);
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: _this code to get ID of li, but I am able to get only ID_ what is the problem?

Comment: _I'm using this code to get ID of li, but I am able to get only ID._ very confusing.....

Comment: please update your question to avoid downvotes

Comment: @Jai - I am using this code in webpart to remove a widget and I need to capture the li ID to remove them, but I am able to get only ul ID.

Comment: @Michael as per your selector `$(this).attr('id')` this would give you the li's ID. BTW what is `#trash`?

Comment: @Jai - trash is the ID of div

Comment: Check your console - you have a rather obvious syntax error.

Comment: share your html also...`alert(this.id);` should give the id...

Comment: This is working, you can check here https://jsfiddle.net/jkhatri6/b15wmsnb/2/ . Please check your console for other syntax errors.

Comment: @JitendraKhatri It's only working because you fixed the mis-matched braces.

Comment: So, it is working at your end now? @Michael

Answer (score 0):

try this

html

```
<div id='trash'>
<ul id='ul'>
    <li id="li">
        list1
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$("#trash ul li").click(function( event ) {
   var $item = $( this )
   $target = $( event.target );
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
    {
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }

   });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LhydD/437/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $item = $(this),
```

Remove `comma` from the end of the above line